# How to bound $\ln z$ on a circumference?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Let $\gamma$ be the upper half the circunference $C(0,R)$ with counter-clockwise orientation

How to prove that

$\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\frac{(\ln z)^2}{z^2 +1} \rightarrow 0$ as $R \rightarrow \infty$

by my calculations this was limited by a constant that does't depends on my $R$

$\displaystyle \frac{(\ln z)^2}{z^2 +1} = \frac{(\ln|z|+iargz)^2}{z^2 +1} \leq \frac{
|z|^2A}{z^2 +1}$ $A$ is something limited as $R \rightarrow \infty$ and in module this quotient tends to a constant $C\neq 0$.

Comment: $(\log |z|+i\arg z)^2 \leq 2(|\log |z||^2+|\arg z|^2)$

Comment: and $(\log|z|)^2 \leq |z|^2$ and the rest putting in evidence are on my $A$ there

Comment: $|z|^2$ grows too fast.

Comment: You can still do the limit for $(\log|z|)^2/(1+|z|^2)$

Answer (score 1):

If $z=Re^{i\theta}$, $R>1$ and $\theta\in(0,\pi)$,
$$\left\|\frac{(\log z)^2}{z^2+1}\right\|\leq \frac{\left\|\log z\right\|^2}{R^2-1}=\frac{\log^2R+\theta^2}{R^2-1}$$
so
$$ \int_\gamma\frac{\log^2 z}{z^2+1}\,dz \ll \frac{\log^2 R}{R} $$
as $R\to +\infty$.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get how you go to $\displaystyle\frac{\log^2 R + \theta^2}{R^2-1}$ to the other limitant

Comment: @EduardoSilva: how large can $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\log^2 R+\theta^2}{R^2-1}\,d\theta$ be?